# laravel routes all messed up, dump-autoload doesn't fix

Tags: php, laravel

Seems like my routes are all messed up. 
My routes and my links go to the wrong places.
Typing in `/user/attendees/index` goes to views/attendees/show.php

Typing in `/user/attendees` goes to /views/attendees/edit

runing artisan dump-autoload and composer dump-autoload does not fix.

What the #$^! is going on?!

artisan routes | grep attendee

```
|        | GET|HEAD user/attendees                                                         | user.attendees.index                      | UserAttendeeController@index                   | auth                                          |               |
|        | GET|HEAD user/attendees/create                                                  | user.attendees.create                     | UserAttendeeController@create                  | auth                                          |               |
|        | POST user/attendees                                                             | user.attendees.store                      | UserAttendeeController@store                   | auth, csrf                                    |               |
|        | GET|HEAD user/attendees/{attendees}                                             | user.attendees.show                       | UserAttendeeController@show                    | auth                                          |               |
|        | GET|HEAD user/attendees/{attendees}/edit                                        | user.attendees.edit                       | UserAttendeeController@edit                    | auth                                          |               |
|        | PUT user/attendees/{attendees}                                                  | user.attendees.update                     | UserAttendeeController@update                  | auth                                          |               |
|        | PATCH user/attendees/{attendees}                                                |                                           | UserAttendeeController@update                  | auth                                          |               |
|        | DELETE user/attendees/{attendees}                                               | user.attendees.destroy
```

routes

```
// User reset routes
Route::get('user/reset/{token}', 'UserController@getReset');
// User password reset
Route::post('user/reset/{token}', 'UserController@postReset');
//:: User Account Routes ::
Route::post('user/{user}/edit', 'UserController@postEdit');
//:: User Account Routes ::
Route::post('user/login', 'UserController@postLogin');

//:: Application Route ::
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'user', 'before' => 'auth'), function()
{

Route::resource('attendees', 'UserAttendeeController');

});


//update the program bookings
Route::post('user/{user}/registration', 'UserController@postRegistration');

# User Implicit User Routes. 
Route::controller('user', 'UserController');
```

Comment: You might want to take a second look at the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) for resourceful routing. The routes you provided in your question show the exact route required, and the controller action called due to that route (for example, GET /user/attendees is the index action, whereas GET /user/attendees/index is the show action where {attendees} = 'index')

Comment: I think my website is not being completed as specified in the routes.

Comment: It is. The output of the `artisan routes` command proves it. Also, make sure that you're going to `/user/attendees` (with an 's'), as shown in your routes. If you try `/user/attendee` (no 's'), you'll get a 404, as that route is not defined.

Comment: Also, if you try to use the `route()` method to generate the link for a named route, your route names are in the second column of the artisan routes output. For example, you would use `route('user.attendees.edit');`, not `route('attendees.edit');`.

Comment: ok I see... `/user/attenees/1/` goes to the show action as expected...`/user/attendee/index` also goes the the show action because it thinks `index` is the parameter for the show($id)...

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: ok I understand my routes now. The one going to the edit route was actually going to the proper controller which was pointed to the wrong view which had a route error inside, hence my confusion. That one was completely my fault for not looking more closely at the error message. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> Typing in /user/attendee/index goes to views/attendees/show.php

Yes, because it's hitting `GET|HEAD user/attendees/{attendees}`, as it should. The index route is `GET|HEAD user/attendees`.

> Typing in /attendee/index goes to NOT found HttpException

None of your routes start with `/attendee/`. The URL you're looking for is probably `/attendees`.

> Typing in /user/attendee looks for Route [attendee.edit] not defined.

Yes, because it matches `Route::controller('user', 'UserController');`

Comment: I was not aware that /attendee/index is supposed to go to show instead of index.

Comment: @Phil It's right there in your routes summary. `GET|HEAD user/attendees | user.attendees.index` Not only is it cleaner, it means Laravel doesn't have to figure out whether you wanted to see the attendee list or find the attendee named `index`.

Comment: You are correct but I don't think we are talking about the same thing. The route you typed above is going to my controller `show` action.

Comment: I deleted the implicit controller `Route::controller('user', 'UserController')` and it still says attendee.edit not defined.
Besides that shouldn't it go to 'UserController@getindex' if it were working correctly?

Comment: sorry I was reporting the wrong output for what I said above. It goes to `views/attendees/index` (which has the route error attendee.edit that is irrelevant to my routing problem)...going to check my route group for user....